# Cannot change DIV text when a UL LI is clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to attempt to add functionality to my UL LI list, such that when an LI item is clicked on, the div's text will change to the selected value of the LI click, however, nothing seems to happen.

Here is the markup and code in question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<style type="text/css">
* {
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-size: 9pt;
}
.select {
    background:url(arrow.png) no-repeat scroll right top;
    border:1px solid rgb(170,170,170);
    width:180px;
    padding: 3px;
}
.select:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.select ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.select ul li {
    display: none;
    padding: 1px;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {

    $(".select").click(function () {
        $(this).find('ul li').toggle();
    });

    $(".select ul li").click(function(e) {

        $(this).find('.select').val($(this).html())

    });

}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="select" id="numbers">Select Box1
    <ul>
        <li>1234</li>
        <li>5678</li>
        <li>0123</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="select" id="letters">Select Box2
    <ul>
        <li>abcd</li>
        <li>efgh</li>
        <li>ijkl</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="select" id="fruits">Select Box3
    <ul>
        <li>apples</li>
        <li>bananas</li>
        <li>oranges</li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the target div is at the parent level of the clicked li, you can use `.closest()` to target the required div element.

```
$(".select").click(function () {
        $(this).find('ul li').toggle();
    });

    $(".select ul li").click(function(e) {
           $(this).closest('div.select').text($(this).html());
    });
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/bvtngh57/150/

Comment: won't this replace the whole div ?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$(".select ul li").on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest("div").contents().first().replaceWith($(this).text());
})
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/4g8asL83/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".select ul li").click(function(e) {

    $(this).parents('.select').html($(this).html())

});
```

Please try this instead of

```
$(".select ul li").click(function(e) {

    $(this).find('.select').val($(this).html())

});
```

This might help you

Answer (score 0):

Use **`closest()`** function to get the parent `.select`, then use **`filter()`** function and condition `this.nodeType == 3` to select only the text, inside the div. Replace it with value, using following.

```js
$(".select").click(function() {
  $(this).find('ul li').toggle();
});

$(".select ul li").click(function(e) {
  $(this).closest('.select').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == 3;
  })[0].textContent = $(this).html()
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  font-size: 9pt;
}
.select {
  background: url(arrow.png) no-repeat scroll right top;
  border: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
  width: 180px;
  padding: 3px;
}
.select:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.select ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.select ul li {
  display: none;
  padding: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select" id="numbers">Select Box1
  <ul>
    <li>1234</li>
    <li>5678</li>
    <li>0123</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="select" id="letters">Select Box2
  <ul>
    <li>abcd</li>
    <li>efgh</li>
    <li>ijkl</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="select" id="fruits">Select Box3
  <ul>
    <li>apples</li>
    <li>bananas</li>
    <li>oranges</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

`$(this).find('.select').val($(this).html());`
to
 
`$(this).parent().parent().html($(this).html());`

```js
window.onload = function() {

    $(".select").click(function () {
        $(this).find('ul li').toggle();
       
    });

    $(".select ul li").click(function(e) {
        // Remove this code
        //$(this).find('.select').val($(this).html());
        // Add this line
        $(this).parent().parent().html($(this).html());
         
    });

}
```

```css
* {
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-size: 9pt;
}
.select {
    background:url(arrow.png) no-repeat scroll right top;
    border:1px solid rgb(170,170,170);
    width:180px;
    padding: 3px;
}
.select:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.select ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.select ul li {
    display: none;
    padding: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select" id="numbers">Select Box1
    <ul>
        <li>1234</li>
        <li>5678</li>
        <li>0123</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="select" id="letters">Select Box2
    <ul>
        <li>abcd</li>
        <li>efgh</li>
        <li>ijkl</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="select" id="fruits">Select Box3
    <ul>
        <li>apples</li>
        <li>bananas</li>
        <li>oranges</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use extra class `hide` so you can control the flow of `hide/show`  and try to give your default text a class for example `default` so you can target it and update it without touching the html of the select with following code :

```
$(this).parents('.select').find('.default').text( $(this).text() );
```

Hope this helps.

---

### Snippet

```js
$(function(){
  $("body").on('click', '.select',function (e) {
    $(this).find('ul li').toggleClass('hide');
  });

  $("body").on('click', '.select ul li', function(e) {
    $(this).parents('.select').find('.default').text( $(this).text() );
  });
})
```

```css
* {
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-size: 9pt;
}
.select {
    background:url(arrow.png) no-repeat scroll right top;
    border:1px solid rgb(170,170,170);
    width:180px;
    padding: 3px;
}
.select:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.select ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.select ul li {
    padding: 1px;
}

.select ul li.hide{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select" id="numbers">
    <span class='default'>Select Box1</span>
    <ul>
        <li class="hide">1234</li>
        <li class="hide">5678</li>
        <li class="hide">0123</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="select" id="letters">
    <span class='default'>Select Box2</span>
    <ul>
        <li class="hide">abcd</li>
        <li class="hide">efgh</li>
        <li class="hide">ijkl</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="select" id="fruits">
    <span class='default'>Select Box3</span>
    <ul>
        <li class="hide">apples</li>
        <li class="hide">bananas</li>
        <li class="hide">oranges</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```